# preg_math getting url within the text

Tags: php

I have a test in which users will be having taggings so I need the url href from the text Like i have a text

```
Hello World <a class="red" contenteditable="false" href="http://domainname.com/demo/forums/profile/test.name">Test </a>&nbsp;this is creating a problem
//I need test.name from the url 

$text = $post_data->discussion;
                    $name = preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $text, $match);

                    print_r($name);
```

Can anyone help me out as I am unable to do so I am failed in making regex

Comment: Do you have to use regexp or can you use a HTML parsing library?

Comment: How many times has this question been answered so far alone here on SO? 56390574903 times?

Comment: @arkascha never asked this question bro why you blaming this to me ?

Comment: I never claimed _you_ have asked that question before. But a simple search through the existing questions here would have given you countless answers for the question without _you_ having to ask it at all ;-)

Comment: bro if I had found and solved the query I had never been asked so please think before you comment I had searched a lot and if you know any one just send me link and would be similar to mine I would appreciate your help rather then such comment brol please do not mind my words sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the anchor tag, that way you'll always get the url (maybe your string contains separate URLs).

```
$str = 'Hello World <a class="red" contenteditable="false" href="http://domainname.com/demo/forums/profile/test.name">Test </a>&nbsp;this is creating a problem';

preg_match_all("/<a.*?href\s*=\s*['\"](.*?)['\"]/", $str, $res, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($res as $key => $val) {
    echo $val[1];
}
// http://domainname.com/demo/forums/profile/test.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
$regex = '/(?<=href="http)s?:\/\/[\w\.\/]+?\K(\w+\.\w+)(?=">)/';
$string = 'Hello World <a class="red" contenteditable="false" href="http://domainname.com/demo/forums/profile/test.name">Test </a>';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

// Outputs
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "test.name"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "test.name"
  }
}
```

Here's an example of it working - https://eval.in/762641